# How to get limited number of distinct records that is above average?

Tags: mysql, subquery

How do I get 2 of the distinct records (including the records with same scores) above the average? Not including the top among rest.

Here's my sample table

| id | scores |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 8.50 |
| 120 | 7.45 |
| 123 | 9.13 |
| 127 | 7.70 |
| 222 | 6.00 |
| 232 | 7.77 |
| 321 | 6.80 |
| 342 | 6.90 |
| 453 | 6.66 |
| 564 | 9.05 |
| 666 | 8.50 |
| 876 | 8.90 |

First, I need to figure out how to get the average.
`avg(scores) = 7.78`

My expected result is:

| id | scores |
| --- | --- |
| 876 | 8.90 |
| 111 | 8.50 |
| 666 | 8.50 |

What I have tried so far:

```
select Examinee_number, score
from examinees
where score > 
    (select avg(score)
    from examinees
    order by score
    limit 2);
```

```
select Examinee_number, score
from examinees
where score >
    (select avg(score)
    from examinees)
    order by score desc
    limit 2;
```

The average should be a reference for scores, in case I only need to get the the scores above the average (score = 8.50) or below the average (score = 7.77).

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, we can use the `RANK()` analytic function here.  For finding the average score excluding the two top highest, we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT score, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rnk
    FROM examinees
)

SELECT AVG(score)
FROM cte
WHERE rnk > 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from `score` where score > (WITH new AS (select * from `score` where score > (SELECT ROUND(AVG(score), 2) FROM `score`) ORDER BY score limit 2) select AVG(score) from new);

select * from score where score < (SELECT AVG(score) FROM `score`) ORDER BY score;
```